# How is Java a Platform independent language?

Tags: java

My knowledge-Java is platform independent because the byte code generated on compilation of source code in one OS can be interpreted by JVM of other OS.
My query:
We install different version of jdk for different OS right,how come the same byte code(generated on compilation of souce code on Mac) for different JVM's i.e JVM(Windows) , JVM(Linux) and JVM(Mac) give the same output.

Comment: Because the bytecode does not depend on the os you compile it on,.

Comment: The JVM is native code for the specific platform, and they all implement the same byte code interpretation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine

Comment: The Java JVM is an "abstraction layer" over the underlying operating system/underlying hardware.  The application uses byte code, instead of (platform-specific!) assembly code.  The application need NOT be written in Java.  Other languages - like Kotlin, Scala, and Groovy - can also generate bytecode that can run in a Java JVM.

Comment: It’s not clear what you are asking. You are saying “the same byte code” but then “for different JVMs”. How can the same thing be different? Are you surprised when different browsers show the same PNG file the same way?

Answer (score 2):

Java is platform independent but the jvm is platform dependent.
Whenever you compile a java program, a .class file is generated which is read by jvm of different machines. ( separate for windows, linux and mac)
The .class file can be read in different machines provided they have the required jvm  which makes java platform independent and jvm as platform dependent.

Comment: @gurikrat Singh Guliani Whatever is absolutely true,but my question is how come same input (.class generated on compilation on windows) when given different platform dependent JVMs giving the corresponding platform's machine code.

Comment: @Asutosh_Baratam are you focussing on the internal working of JVM ?

Comment: @gurikrat singh guliana i guess i dived deep ,conclusion i got from answers is jvm is built in such manner that any system's .class file can be converted to corresponding system machine code.need to embrace it blindly.